# /etc/network/interfaces file valdiation

Tags: networking, testing

Are there any tools baked in to linux that I can use to validate the syntax in `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/network/interfaces/*.conf` files akin to the way I can validate sudo using `visudo` before installing it.

I'm writing scripts to be deployed in the old "internet-of-things-that-aught-to-be-set-up-right-in-the-first-place-but-most-likely-aren't" methodology and want to unit test my config generators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command `ifup --no-act --interfaces=/home/user/interfaces.new eth0` to check for syntax errors in a specified interface file on an interface that is already up.

If errors exist you will get a message stating the incorrect line number and something about being unable to parse the interface file.

If there are no errors, then you will get a message stating that the interface is already configured.

You can check the return value of the command by looking at the value of the `$?` variable after running the command in your script.

**Look at `man ifup` for more information.**

Comment: ifup has to read from interfaces it can see, not an arbitrary location. So if I have to re-configure an interface, backing up the interface config, running that `ifup --no-act` copying in my new one and restoring it if there are shell errors is the way to go.   It's a little risky, but oh well. Doing it in python so I should be able to catch exceptions easy enough.

Comment: `ifup --no-act --interfaces=/home/user/interfaces.new eth0`